# Why does this static positioned div moves upward from its position?

Tags: javascript, html, css

This seems a very frustrating issue in my blog. I can reproduce it only in Chrome (60+). The main div (`.columns.fauxcolumns`) where the header and content are displayed **is cropped from the top**. Basically it's hidden (`overflow:hidden` is there) and somehow it is 10-20 pixels upwards from its normal position; flows out of `.columns.fauxcolumns`, even it (`.colums-inner`) is static.

How to inspect / re-produce:

1. Please visit https://sourcewing.blogspot.in/search/label/articles
2. `Control + Click` on **MORE** in the first article (to open in new tab)
3. **Before** the page is loaded fully in the tab that you've just opened, click on the tab and DON'T SCROLL the page. SCROLL UP ONLY WHEN PAGE IS FULLY LOADED.
4. When you'll scroll up, you'll probably find the issue.

You might not find it with just one try as it's produced in this scenario only.

Why is it happening? I know we can somehow fix it but I believe it's not a normal issue as it is observed only in Chrome.

The following screenshot might help:

Note: **November 28, 2015** is cropped in screenshot.

[image]

Comment: I believe this is more of a bug than a issue.

Comment: Yes, it's a JavaScript bug.

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue being the `loading` class not been removed after the page has loaded. This is something to do with JavaScript. The correct one should be the script should automatically remove the `loading` class from `<body>`. Since this being a show-stopper in the presentation, it can be kinda fixed using the following CSS:

```css
.loading .main-inner .columns.fauxcolumns {
  overflow: visible;
}
```

Comment: If you see, `.columns-inner` moves outside of `.columns.fauxcolumns` That's really strange and that's the problem. Don't know why is it happening.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49248020/why-does-static-div-moves-out-of-relative-positioned-div?noredirect=1#comment85505345_49248020